# What component is needed to collect injector pulse?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, opto-isolator, signal-processing, pulse

I am planning to convert this pulse to a digital signal (apx. 5 V for MCU input) based on voltage level. The maximum voltage of this pulse is 12 V when the injector nozzle is closed and 0 V otherwise. Also, the smallest pulse width is 2 μs.

I don't know which components to use. Is it an optocoupler and an N-type MOSFET? Any recommendation of series or other components and method to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a logic-output optoisolator and connect the output directly to the MCU. For example, [this](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/408/TLP2348_datasheet_en_20191126-1316060.pdf) one, which is inexpensive and switches typically in well under 100ns, and should do the job for 5V MCU supply voltage.

Note that the isolation is not adequate to protect against ignition wire voltages. If you need to protect against accidental discharge then more parts would be required.

Input circuit could just be a 2K series resistor and a reverse-biased 1N4148 across the LED to protect it.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVX1Fn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'm a little concerned about the LED. The maximum input forward voltage is 1.65V. Meanwhile, the injector pulse is up to 12V.

Comment: That's why the 2kΩ series resistor.. it will limit the current to around 5mA with 12V in. The threshold will be around 4.4V.

Comment: I'm sorry for still not understanding what it means. What calculations are done to be able to determine the threshold is 4.4V when the input is 12V and the current is 5mA for the LED input? Or is it in the datasheet? As far as I understand it is Vf and If as variable/pin that connected to injector wire.

Comment: The current is approximately (Vin - 1.55)/R1, so for 12V it is ~5.2mA.  The 1.55V is the Vf of the LED at 3mA. At 5mA it will typically be a bit higher. The threshold current is 1.6mA  max (from the datasheet), so Vin = 4.8V (I used 1.2V for Vf which is a bit lower than the datasheet but at 1.6mA Vf will be lower).

Comment: The optocoupler responds to LED *current*, just like current through a visible LED.The resistor turns the input voltage into an appropriate level of current. If you connect 12V to the LED directly, it will be destroyed. Also you should not put more than 5V reverse voltage across the LED so the 1N4148 (+ R1) protects the LED against that, in case of transients or wrong connection.

Comment: I want to make sure my understanding about that formula. If the current through LED need to be reduced, then I have to increase the resistor value. For example 4.7kΩ will result in a current at 12V voltage is 2.22 mA. Is it correct? I think i need to do this since the injector pulse generates a voltage spike up to 30V at the transition when nozzle is open to close. So that, maximum current (spiked pulse) is 6 mA.

Comment: Although, this isn't necessary as input forward current rating is 15 mA and that make 2kΩ is enough for 30V spiked pulse.

Comment: I would not worry about those spikes, it's good for 15mA **continuous** (~31V) and pulsed 1A 1us 300pps (2kV). If you go too low reliability may be affected by temperature changes or LED aging.